# Difference between java.version and maven.compiler.target

Tags: java, maven

There could be two different properties as of specifying java version in maven properties:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>7</java.version>
</properties>
```

and

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties>
```

What is the difference and when to use what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two ways of configuring the Java version produces exactly the same result.

1) This is the [standard Maven way](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to value source and target Java versions :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties>
```

2) While that is a [Spring Boot specificity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-java-version) :

```
<properties>
    <java.version>7</java.version>
</properties>
```

It is a shortcut property to not declare both the source and the target version as these have the same value.

From [the spring-boot-starter-parent pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml), we can see that `java.version` is used to value `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` :

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    .... 
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

This way may make sense as the most of time, source and target version are the case (but it is not a standard way).

---

If you develop a Spring Boot application, you can choose the one or the other.
Otherwise, only the second should be used.